# Convert a list of integers into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to convert the following list : `items = [[1,91],[1,92],[2,93],[2,97],[1,60],[2,77],[1,65],[1,87],[1,100],[2,100],[2,76]]`

into following dictionary:

```
d = {1: [91,92,60,...], 2:[93,97,77,...]}
```

I've tried the weirdest things like :

```
d = {}
for i,k in items:
  d[i] = [k for i,k in items]
```

but I get an TypeError. Any easy to implement suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a defaultdict object from the collections module. This will allow you to insert elements and if the key didnt exist it will create it on the fly.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


def grouper(items):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for (key, val) in items:
        grouped[key].append(val)
    return grouped



nums = [(1, 90), (1, 54), (2, 45), (2, 43)]
output = grouper(nums)
print(output)
print(output[1])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [90, 54], 2: [45, 43]})
[90, 54]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setdefault`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm):

```py
dict_items = {}
for k, v in items:
    dict_items.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# The type hints are Python 3.9+
def convert(items: list[list[int, int]]) -> dict[int, list[int]]:
    out = {}
    for item in items:
        out_list = out.get(item[0], [])
        out_list.append(item[1])
        out[item[0]] = out_list
    return out
```

This is O(n).

line 4: This defines what you’re going to set the value as in the out dict. If you haven’t already set a value for that key, use an empty list. This is similar to `defaultdict` but more explicit and doesn’t require an import.

---

If you want something closer to what you were using before:

```py
def convert(items: list[list[int, int]]) -> dict[int, list[int]]:
    return {k: [v_ for k_, v_ in items if k_ == k] for k, _ in items}
```

This is O(n²). Even if a key has already been set, it will be checked again. You can see this with the following snippet:

```py
import random

def foo(i):
    out = random.randint(1, 1000)
    print(f"foo called with i={i}, returning {out}")
    return out

print({k: foo(k) for k in [1, 2, 3, 1]})
```

Example output:

```
foo called with i=1, returning 285
foo called with i=2, returning 175
foo called with i=3, returning 404
foo called with i=1, returning 380
{1: 380, 2: 175, 3: 404}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! What does the _ in  "for k, _ in items" at the end of the 2nd code? Shouldn't it be k_ ?

Comment: It’s fairly standard practice to call a variable `_` if you don’t plan on using it. Here, I only want they key, I don’t need the value. An alternative would be not unpacking and instead do `for item in items` and replace `k` with `item[0]`, without ever using `item[1]`. The nested comprehension has trailing underscores in the names just so they’re name differently.